# Binary file turns out smaller on Windows than on Linux

Tags: c++, file, binary

I'm working on a program that writes binary data to a file. On Windows, the resulting file is slightly smaller than on Linux for some reason. The size in bytes and the MD5 hash are both different. How can this happen with the same code?

I already added the `ifstream::binary` flag and I made sure I set `noskipws`...

```
ofstream output("output", ifstream::binary);
output << std::noskipws;
```

I ran Application Verifier on my program and it didn't generate any errors or warnings regarding possible memory corruption.

Are there any other reasons why file output might be different?

Comment: Can you please post a complete program that exposes this effect?

Comment: try comparing those files using a hex editor and see what the difference is.

Comment: what type of binary data are writing - is it text?

Comment: Formatted output is hardly a good way to get platform-independent behaviour. If anything, we can discuss how portable *raw* output is.

Comment: As an aside, what is `std::noskipws` supposed to do on an output file? Why are you opening an `ofstream` using `ifstream::binary`? The code might work, but overall it looks rather...confused and confusing.

Comment: `ifstream::binary` was indeed a stupid oversight that has since been fixed. As for `std::noskipws`, I know that with `ifstream`s it prevents the stream from skipping over whitespace, so I thought maybe whitespace would not be written to the binary stream if I didn't enable that setting.

Comment: @JosephH: We're in the process of comparing `xxd` output in a diff viewer. @Björn: I haven't been able to narrow down the glitch, so I can't post sample code yet. @juergen: bare-bones binary data. I use a bit stream reader/writer that lets you write `uint8_t`s with a specified cut-off length like `put(int numBitsToUse, uint8_t data)`. This bit stream reader/writer doesn't seem to be at fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is probably due to different development environments. Different compilers, hardware and operating systems can all change the format of the underlying data. For example, the different compilers may pack your data structures with varying amounts of efficiency. Also, your basic types (ints, longs, floats, etc) may be different sizes due to different processors.

In short, programs that require cross-platform compatibility between binary data develop very precise rules for packing structures and values into binary format (often at the field, and equally precise rules for reading the data.

Comment: *For example, the different compilers may pack your data structures with varying amounts of efficiency.* I'm going to investigate this angle further. You're probably right about this being the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing exactly what you're writing to the file and how you are calling it, it's hard to give a truly useful answer, but if you're using the stream insertion operator (aka formatted output operator) to do your file writing, then any non-string data will be converted into strings according to your locale settings.  If that is what you are actually doing, using `ofstream::binary` seems somewhat pointless, because you are just writing text anyway.

I would recommend creating the smallest possible example for which there is a difference and examining the output in a hex editor to see what is going on.